# Font-Awesome icons move when page is made smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

/* icon sect*/

```
.social {
  margin-top: px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.social li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: ;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #004d26;
  z-index: 1;
}

.social li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: ;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ff003b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.social li:hover:before {
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.social li:hover {
 color: #979FA8;
}
```

Hello, all. So, I'm having this issue where if I click and hold on the bottom of my web page and decide to pull up, minimizing the screen, my font awesome icons move with it. I would like to have my icons stay exactly where they're at and not move at all. Thank you for the help! and if I am somehow repeating someone's question, I apologize. I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Is there a working example?

Comment: There isn't, I apologize. The website isn't live and it doesn't come out right on codepen.

Comment: Well that's happening because of you {  position: absolute; top: 60%;left: 50%;}. I dont know what you are trying to achieve here. But position absolute is causing the propblem.

Comment: Err.. there is nothing to run in your link.

Comment: I did that because I ran into an alignment issue. I'm trying to keep the two buttons center, and if I take out the {position: absolute;top 60%;left: 50%;} and change the number, the buttons end up either top left, top right, bottom left, or bottom right.

Comment: And don't judge when it comes to the layout. It's a work in progress, lol. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Hey .. I have been there too! So your problem seems to be to centrally align the icon. I am right?

Comment: No, the icons are aligned and dead center right above the "where am i text" in the white space that sits in between the blue and the shadow of the jumbotron. However, if I minimize the screen by dragging the bottom of the screen up, the icons move up with the screen. Everything else stays put, just those two icons move up. They still stay centered, but the move. Im trying to figure out how I keep them planted in their spots.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQEjaJ I have made some edits.. does this help? Tell me, if it does.. I will explain what I did. Concentrate on the positioning .. I have delted the color and other css to make things simple.

Comment: Yes! that works! what did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to HTML and CSS!! [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS) is the best place to learn.

Here is the [edited code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQEjaJ) which works (what I believe) in the way you want (not really the ideal way to do).

I removed the absolute positioning of the element. Since you just wanted to centrally align the element I used text-align : center;

Use absolute positioning if you want to fix the element w.r.t the parent (a relative positioned element).

changed the styles of class .social

```
.social {
  text-align: center;
}
```

and added `display: inline-block;`instead of `float: left;` under selector `.social li`

```
.social li {
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Happy coding.
P.S. you can use already built templates  of bootstrap to make about me pages.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I'll check those templates out!